# Mounting a Wester Digital MyBook returns mount error(22): invalid argument

Tags: mount, samba, nfs, cifs, network-drive

I tried mounting my WD MyBook like this:

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.x.x /mnt -o guest
```

But I get the error:

```
mount error(22): Invalid argument
```

I tried the usual mount commands but eventually this worked for me.

With user name and pass:

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.x.x/Public /mount_location -o username=<name>,password=<pass>,vers=1.0,rw
```

Without user name and pass:

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.x.x/Public /mount_location -o guest,vers=1.0,rw
```

The only explanation I have for this is that version has to be specified if you have an old WD MyBook as well as read write access requested.

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking why it requires the passing of the vers=1.0 option?

mount.cifs is controlled by the Linux kernel and it will negotiate with the server the best smb dialect ( vers ) to use between a max value and a min value.

Beginning with Linux Kernel version 4.13.5 the max is 3.xx and the min is 2.1.

If the server is very old and is not capable of SMBv2.1 or greater you will get an invalid argument error.

The only way out of this is explicitly add a lower dialect level like vers=1.0 or vers=2.0.